# Find the occurences of different keys in a file has multiple columns in C++

Tags: c++, parsing, data-processing

I have a file in the format as belows. I've done parsing it. I have the code to find the occurences of each key by switch-case or if(). But I want to find a better way to do it. Here's the message I need to parse then find occurence of keys. We can see the message on each row is tokenized by ";", can be considered it as 7 columns. The element on column 2 is known as "Name". We can understand if a name appears on each row means its occurence should be incremented. I want to find total occurence of each key name: AMD, OTHER...

```
09:00:15.390001;AMD;2837197;I;BUY;111;35.20
09:00:15.680001;AMD;2837197;C;BUY;111;35.20
09:00:16.040001;AMD;2837198;I;BUY;20;35.00
09:00:16.500001;AMD;2837196;C;BUY;1;35.10
09:00:16.860001;DVAM2;2837181;C;SELL;36;9.30
09:00:16.870001;AMD;2837198;C;BUY;20;35.00
09:00:17.310001;AMD;2837199;I;SELL;8;36.10
09:00:18.920001;AMD;2837200;I;SELL;9;36.10
09:00:19.190001;DVAM2;2837201;I;SELL;9;9.00
09:00:19.650001;AMD;2837202;I;SELL;160;35.90
09:00:19.940001;OTHER;2837180;C;BUY;7;18.40
09:00:19.960001;AMD;2837202;C;SELL;160;35.90
09:00:20.210001;AMD;2837199;C;SELL;8;36.10
09:00:20.550001;AMD;2837200;C;SELL;9;36.10
09:00:20.640001;AMD;2837203;I;BUY;4;35.70
09:00:21.400001;OTHER;2837204;I;BUY;6;18.20
09:00:21.460001;AMD;2837205;I;BUY;5;35.50
09:00:22.110001;AMD;2837203;A;BUY;4;35.70
09:00:22.350001;DVAM2;2837201;C;SELL;9;9.00
09:00:22.430001;OTHER;2837206;I;BUY;8;18.10
09:00:22.650001;TEST1;2837207;I;SELL;1;32.70
09:00:23.410001;AMD;2837208;I;SELL;9;36.40
09:00:23.420001;AMD;2837208;C;SELL;9;36.40
09:00:24.140001;AMD;2837205;C;BUY;5;35.50
09:00:24.980001;TEST0;2837182;C;SELL;76;23.20
09:00:25.310001;DVAM2;2837185;C;SELL;3;9.00
09:00:25.470001;AMD;2837203;C;BUY;4;35.70
09:00:25.470001;AMD;2837209;I;BUY;4;35.20
09:00:25.470001;OTHER;2837206;C;BUY;8;18.10
09:00:25.630001;TEST0;2837210;I;BUY;3;22.90
09:00:26.020001;AMD;2837209;C;BUY;4;35.20
09:00:26.480001;AMD;2837211;I;SELL;8;36.00
09:00:26.960001;AMD;2837211;C;SELL;8;36.00
09:00:27.060001;AMD;2837212;I;SELL;5;36.20
09:00:27.350001;AMD;2837213;I;BUY;9;35.30
09:00:27.690001;OTHER;2837204;C;BUY;6;18.20
09:00:27.960001;TEST4;2837214;I;SELL;9;16.20
```

Here's my code

```
// IManager.h
class inventory
{
    public:
          std::unordered_map<std::string, int64_t> orderCountPerDVAM1Symbol, orderCountPerDVAM2Symbol, orderCountPerOTHERSymbol;
}

//BManager.cpp
    // Order count of each key, e.g. DVAM1 as you see in the attached photo will be increased no matter we seel or buy it. 
    int64_t inventory::orderCounts(std::string symbols)
    {
        if (sellHead != NULL && orderCountPerDVAM1Symbol.find(symbols) != orderCountPerDVAM1Symbol.end() && symbols == "DVAM1")
            orderCountPerDVAM1Symbol[sellTail->symbol]++; // increment order count when selling     
        
        if (buyHead != NULL && orderCountPerDVAM1Symbol.find(symbols) != orderCountPerDVAM1Symbol.end() && symbols == "DVAM1")
            orderCountPerDVAM1Symbol[buyTail->symbol]++; // increment order count when buying       
                                                    
        return orderCountPerDVAM1Symbol[sellTail->symbol];
    }



// main.cpp   
    struct messageData // Defining one row of message data
    {
        // Message Format: timestamp;symbol;order-id;operation;side;volume;price
    
        std::string timestamp;
        std::string symbol;
        unsigned long long int orderid;
        char operation; 
        char side;  
        unsigned long int volume; 
        float price;
    };
    
    int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
    {
        messageData inMsg;
    
        std::ifstream messageStream("test1.txt"); //orders coding test developer.dat
        std::ofstream logBook("_LogBook.txt", std::ios::out);
    
        int64_t orderCountDVAM1, orderCountDVAM2, orderCountOther, orderCount0, orderCount1, orderCount2, orderCount3, orderCount4, orderCount5, orderCount6, orderCount7;
    
    while (std::getline(messageStream, messageLine)) // Loop until last line of message stream
        {
            std::stringstream lineStream(messageLine); // Read each message line
            std::cout << "Message row no." << messageRow << ":\n" << messageLine << '\n'; // For test purposes
    
            cellID = 0; // cellID: 0(timestamp); 1(symbol); 2(order-id), 3(operation); 4(side); 5(volume); 6(price)
            while (std::getline(lineStream, messageCell, ';') && cellID < 8) // Loop & Quality check until last cell of message line
            {
              ....
               cellID++;
            }
            if(messageTestPassed)
            {
              vol.push_back(inMsg.symbol);
            }
            // Next message line will be read from the stream and the cycle repeated.
            messageRow++; // Increment message row number.
            std::cout << '\n';
    
            for (auto symbol : vol) {
                orderCount = inventory.orderCounts(symbol);
                std::cout << "\t\t\t\tTOTAL Order count = " << orderCount << '\n';
                
            }
            logBook << "\t\t\t\tTOTAL Order count = " << myLTOS(orderCount) << '\n';
            logBook.close();
            return 0;
    }
```

The problem is that I got wrong value of occurence for each key. As in this photo
[Occurence finding wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88VBi.jpg)

```
Msg #1  09:00:00.440000;AMD;2837174;I;SELL;72;36.30
                TOTAL AMD Order count = 
Msg #2  09:00:00.690000;TEST8;2837175;I;BUY;9;9.60
                TOTAL AMD Order count = 1
Msg #3  09:00:00.730000;AMD;2837176;I;SELL;5;36.30
                TOTAL AMD Order count = 3
Msg #4  09:00:01.040000;AMD;2837177;I;SELL;2;36.60
                TOTAL AMD Order count = 6
Msg #5  09:00:01.170000;AMD;2837174;A;SELL;72;36.00             
                TOTAL AMD Order count = 9
Msg #6  09:00:01.580000;AMD;2837178;I;SELL;620;36.00
                TOTAL AMD Order count = 13
Msg #7  09:00:02.030000;AMD;2837179;I;BUY;59;35.20
                TOTAL AMD Order count = 23
Msg #8  09:00:02.270000;OTHER;2837180;I;BUY;7;18.40 
                TOTAL AMD Order count = 33
Msg #9  09:00:03.040000;DVAM2;2837181;I;SELL;36;9.30
                TOTAL AMD Order count = 43
Msg #10 09:00:03.240000;TEST0;2837182;I;SELL;76;23.20   
                TOTAL AMD Order count = 5
Msg #11 09:00:03.410000;AMD;2837177;C;SELL;2;36.60              
                TOTAL AMD Order count = 10
Msg #12 09:00:03.600000;AMD;2837174;C;SELL;72;36.00             
                TOTAL Order count = 16
Msg #13 09:00:04.170000;OTHER;2837183;I;BUY;8;18.20 
                TOTAL AMD Order count = 22
Msg #14 09:00:04.340000;AMD;2837179;C;BUY;59;35.20              
                TOTAL AMD Order count = 29
Msg #15 09:00:04.580000;AMD;2837184;I;BUY;3;35.10   
                TOTAL AMD Order count = 37
```

Expection: Get result from Msg 1~15 should be
TOTAL AMD Order count = 10. Above the wrong result is 37.

Even if the result is correct, this method is inefficient, as it's very time consuming to check each ticket name, e.g. AMD, NVDA, TSLA... there're thousands of ticket name. So if(), switch-case method to increment counter each time we find it in the map is not good, or unodered_map is good for this application and this wrong result is simply because of my wrong implementation? I hope you can help me with code modification, or suggest me a direction.

Comment: This code does not compile. It is incomplete. Post a complete code (but minimal complete code) that exhibits the problem. Also, you gave us the invalid output, but we also need the expected valid output.

Comment: In the process of putting together a minimal complete code that exhibits the problem you may very well find the cause, and also the fix. In that case you don't need us anymore.

Comment: @Dialecticus I designed my code into several cpp and h files, so it's not easy to gather those into 1 post to let others compile. Can you write sample code with the message format & my expectation as editted above? Sorry my any inconvenience. I'll try to put those codes into a compilable post if you still want to see it, but not immediately.

Comment: Following looks incorrect: `std::unordered_map<std::string, int64_t> orderCountPerDVAM1Symbol;
    if (sellHead != NULL && orderCountPerDVAM1Symbol.find(symbols) != orderCountPerDVAM1Symbol.end() && symbols == "DVAM1")`

You define the `orderCountPerDVAM1Symbol` just before checking and expect it to have values.

Comment: @Aamir Sorry. It's not my formal code. I decleared orderCountPerDVAM1Symbol in a header file. I just modified it and put in function orderCounts() in this post so you guys can see it clearly, as I can't post all of my code here. I've modified my post. Please help me check it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it by myself using switch(cellID) when we meet a corresponding name in the column 2. I got the expecting result. Anyways, I still welcome someone suggests me a more optimized solution as my solution may not be the best one.